# How to reset firebase captcha in react using firebase/sdk

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I copied the code from this bit here in the documentation:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function(widgetId) {
  grecaptcha.reset(widgetId);
}
```

Where do we get grecaptcha?

Answer (score 0):

It's a separate library. Btw in react you might have to do `window.grecaptcha`

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"></script>
```